# Uncaught ReferenceError: <function> is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below codes in my jsp file.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var date = new Date();
        var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);

        function getFirstDay() {
            return firstDay;
        }
        ;

        function getToday() {
            return date;
        }
        ;
    });
</script>

<script>
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format : 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        todayHighlight : true
    });

    $("#from_date").datepicker("setDate", getFirstDay());
    $("#to_date").datepicker("setDate", getToday());
    $("#from_date").datepicker('update');
    $("#to_date").datepicker('update');
</script>
```

But when page load, I got below error on js console.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: getFirstDay is not defined
```

How could I solve this ?

Comment: See [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: You only need code in `$(document).ready()` when you are accessing DOM elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the function that are to be called you should not put them in `document.ready()` make them global so that they can be accessible.

change your code to this:

```
<script>

function getFirstDay() {

        var date = new Date();
        var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
        return firstDay;

        }

function getToday() {

            return new Date();
        }

</script>
```

and now call it:

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format : 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        todayHighlight : true
    });

    $("#from_date").datepicker("setDate", getFirstDay());
    $("#to_date").datepicker("setDate", getToday());
    $("#from_date").datepicker('update');
    $("#to_date").datepicker('update');
 });
</script>
```

Comment: ... A warning about how global functions / vars are bad?

Comment: You can simplify `getToday` function by `return new Date();`. Also `getFirstDay` function can be simplified in same way as `getToday`